# How to set +60Hz refresh rate with an Intel CPU?

Tags: intel-graphics, refresh-rate

In the past I've set 144Hz refresh rate in Nvidia control panel. After removing the GPU from my PC I'm stuck at 60Hz (the monitor settings are identical, no changes):

[image: Intel CPU control panel]

My CPU is Intel Core i7-4770K.

Comment: What is the model of your processor?

Comment: @zandermar18: Intel Core i7-4770K, updated the question.

Comment: Since two users answered almost at the same time using the same reference, I'll accept the answer which was submitted earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Intel i7-4770k only supports up to 60Hz refresh rate since the onboard graphics (Intel HD 4600) only supports that. This is shown in the product specification in the screenshot below:

[image]

The product page is here: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75123/intel-core-i7-4770k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html

So unfortunately, you're stuck at a maximum of 60Hz using the onboard graphics.

Answer (score 3):

That's all it can do, 60Hz is the maximum refresh rate the on-chip GPU can achieve.

Ref: Intel Ark - [Intel® Core™ i7-4770K Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75123/intel-core-i7-4770k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html)

Answer (score -3):

Follow

Custom Resolution > Click 'Yes' > Set resolution and refresh rate manually.

Comment: This appears to be a copy of an existing answer.  Why?